# How to specify elements in selenium selector

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

This is my code that works:

```
name = selector.xpath('//title/text()').get()
print(name)
```

The output of the above code:
`No broker | Crunchbase`

But then for the following code, it doesn't work:

```
##Intro of the company
intro = selector.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"component--field-formatter field-type-text_long ng-star-inserted")]/text()')
print(intro)
```

The output of the above code:

```
[<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"location_identifiers")]/text()' data=' Bangalore'>, <Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"location_identifiers")]/text()' data=' Karnataka'>, <Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"location_identifiers")]/text()' data=' India'>, <Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"location_identifiers")]/text()' data=' India'>]
```

This is the url:
https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/nobroker#section-overview

How can I only get Bangalore, Karnataka, India in the second code?
I think the problem lies in /text?
The first /text works but the second doesn't. How should I make it work to only get the text?
Thanks a lot!!
It would be very much appreciated if you could suggest me some documentations regarding how to **scrape** snippets of data using selenium selector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are getting back a web element that is stored in memory somewhere. just add a `.text` to the end.

```
intro = selector.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"component--field-formatter field-type-text_long ng-star-inserted")]/text()').text
print(intro)
```

If it is a list you can do the same thing but in a for loop

```
intro = selector.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"component--field-formatter field-type-text_long ng-star-inserted")]/text()')
for i in intro:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: it said: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: he resuelto con tu código

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting a list of web elements. You need to both navigate the list and get the text attribute from the element

```
elements = selector.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"component--field-formatter field-type-text_long ng-star-inserted")]/text()')
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_property('innerText'))
```